# Enemy Ai unityscript movement issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, unityscript

The code I am using currently makes the enemy notice me at a distance then follow me if I get closer. The issue I am having is with how they move. I am building a Minecraft style game but I cant get the enemies to stay on the ground and jump up each block like I have too with the fps controller. They just seem to float the shortest distance possible towards me.

Code:

```js
 var target : Transform; //the enemy's target
 var moveSpeed = 3; //move speed
 var rotationSpeed = 3; //speed of turning
 var range : float=10f;
 var range2 : float=10f;
 var stop : float=0;
 var myTransform : Transform; //current transform data of this enemy
 function Awake()
 {
     myTransform = transform; //cache transform data for easy access/preformance
 }

 function Start()
 {
      target = GameObject.FindWithTag("1Player").transform; //target the player

 }

 function Update () {
     //rotate to look at the player
     var distance = Vector3.Distance(myTransform.position, target.position);
     if (distance<=range2 &&  distance>=range){
     myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,
     Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
     }


     else if(distance<=range && distance>stop){

     //move towards the player
     myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,
     Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
     myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
     }
     else if (distance<=stop) {
     myTransform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation,
     Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform.position), rotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
     }


 }
```

Comment: That is what your code is written to do, have them float directly toward you.  You can either try to set up a Navmesh (although I don't know if it would work well in an ever-changing 3d environment) or find/write your own more complex AI navigation script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay now here is what you are missing:

1.Lock the rotation on x and z axis to zero

```
myTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, myTransform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
```

Just add this line at the end.

2.Make a short distance raycast in front of the AI and if it detects some obstacle, stop the current movement and move by y axis, if there is no obstacle move like you wrote in your script.

As for the raycasting goes, there is no need for me to write it here, you can find more info about it in Unity3D documentation here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html and this tutorial is good for staters: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/raycasting

Comment: Looks like a good place to start for a newcomer, but I'm pretty sure that will only let the enemies go uphill, not downhill.  To be robust in a minecraft-type world I think might be actually really hard.

Comment: Hahaha sorry I totally forgot about downhill, add another raycast that shoots beneath the player with the direction of going down, and if it hits something really close (means the ground is right bellow) continue with your script, else fall down.

Comment: Could also try to use the physics to take care of that and move it using forces instead of directly manipulating the transform, might have some unintended (but possibly fun!) consequences.

Comment: @NotAGenie Had a look at that tutorial but I cant seem to get it working, had to revert to original code with the lock on x and z axis for now. Also when I get out of the enemys view again they seem to just float off?